# Тесты JUnit4 проходят по-отдельности, а при запуске всего файла с тестами часть проваливается (Java)

Tags: java, тестирование, junit

Я новичок в программировании. Написал несколько юнит-тестов. По-отдельности они все проходят. При запуске всего файла целиком появляются ошибки по некоторым из них, например:

Есть такой тест

```
    @org.junit.Test
    public void getTitle() {
        Deanery dekanat=new Deanery();
        Group.addGroup("testTitle");
        assertEquals("testTitle", Deanery.groupList.get(0).getTitle());
    }
```

В ArrayList "groupList" создается новая группа студентов с названием 
"testTitle".
В тесте сравниваю название группы, полученное из геттера, со строкой.

При запуске всего файла с тестами выдает следующее:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :testTitle
Actual   :testGroup
```

Причем в этом тесте названия "testGroup" вообще нет (но в других тестах есть).
Складывается ощущение, что JUnit не очищает данные при переходе из теста в тест. При запуске в режиме debug так оно и происходит.

Чем может быть вызвано такое его поведение и как это исправить? Или что я делаю не так?
В любом случае спасибо!

Comment: В коде есть статические переменные?

Comment: Да, как минимум сам arrayList статический

Comment: Можно как-то проинициализировать список перед началом тестов.

Comment: @RomanC опционально, но лучше все же избавится от нее, если это возможно

Comment: @Stranger От кого избавиться?

Comment: @RomanC от статики)

Comment: @Stranger Тестировщик не может менять код, написанный разработчиком без особого на это разрешения, которого быть не может в случае если  по спецификации поле должно быть статическим, и ты уже пиши тесты нормально.

Comment: @RomanC Я сам пишу юнит тесты на свой код, частенько еще перед его написанием, и Вам советую

Comment: @Stranger ты молодец, что начинаешь писать тесты сразу, но потом в конце тебе надо будет покрыть весь код, ну и тесты должны работать перед комитом.

Comment: @RomanC нет на столько я не параноюсь, я обычно пишу тесты только на конвертеры всякие и сложную логику, а не на все подряд

Comment: @Stranger Правильно - богу богово, а кесарю - кесарево, занимался тем что тебе больше нравиться.

Comment: @RomanC ну они (тесты) больше всего нужны мне, нот я их и пишу

Comment: @Stranger Я понял, это не совсем хорошо с твоей стороны, так как если ты пишешь код не для себя, то тестами будут пользоваться другие, и качество тестов для них имеет более важное значение чем для тебя.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно статические переменные живут пока не завершится программа загрузившая класс с этой статикой. Статика инициализируется один раз, при загрузке класса класс-лоадером. "Обычно" я написал потому, что есть возможность изменить это поведение, за счет переписанного класс лоадера, как это сделано например в [реализациях OSGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)

Я так полагаю Ваши тесты меняют значение статической переменной, и вы ожидаете что значение этих полей будет "как при старте программы", но это не так, в них сохраняются значения от предыдущих запусков тестов, т.к. все тесты запускаются в рамках одного запуска jvm

PS: С вашими тестами 2 пути, либо Вы вручную перед запуском каждого теста явно руками инициализируете статику как надо, либо избавляетесь от нее и от проблем с ней.

Comment: Я понял, большое Вам спасибо!
Значит буду править код и избавляться от статических переменных.

Comment: Только какой класс-лоадер используется не совсем понятно.

Comment: @RomanC в OSGI? вот тут смотрите например https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.framework/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader

Comment: При чем здесь OSGI?

Comment: @RomanC я его привел в качестве примера, в нем реализован класс лоадер, который может выгружать классы и  статику вместе с ними.